# Sockets: .NET Core 2 server, HTML5 client cannot connect

Tags: asp.net, html, sockets

I've run into a problem with socket server. Hope any of you might help me.
I have server built in .NET Core running on Debian which worked fine for clients made in .NET, but when I try to use HTML client it never gets past handshake.

Here's my example server:

```
class Program
{
    public static TcpListener listener;
    private static List<ClientPacket> clients;
    private const int port = 4245;
    private const int bufferSize = 1024;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        clients = new List<ClientPacket>();
        listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
        listener.Start();
        StartListening();

        while (true)
        {
        }
    }

    private static void StartListening()
    {
        listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(AcceptClient, listener);
    }

    private static void AcceptClient(IAsyncResult res)
    {
        TcpClient client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(res);
        client.NoDelay = true;

        ClientPacket packet = new ClientPacket(client);
        clients.Add(packet);

        Console.WriteLine("Client connected");
        client.Client.BeginReceive(packet.buffer, 0, bufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveMessage), packet);
        StartListening();
    }

    private static void ReceiveMessage(IAsyncResult res)
    {
        ClientPacket packet = (ClientPacket)res.AsyncState;
        Socket s = packet.client.Client;

        try
        {
            if (s.EndReceive(res) > 0)
            {
                s.BeginReceive(packet.buffer, 0, bufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveMessage), packet);
            }
            else
            {
                clients.Remove(packet);
                s.Close();
                packet = null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            clients.Remove(packet);
            s.Close();
            packet = null;
        }

    }
```

It simply accepts clients, adds them to list and removes them after connection is lost. Problem is when I try it with this HTML5 client (copied from example tutorial):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

      <script type="text/javascript">
         function WebSocketTest()
         {
            if ("WebSocket" in window)
            {
               var ws = new WebSocket("ws://serverIP:4245");

               ws.onopen = function()
               {
                  ws.send("Message to send");
                  alert("Message is sent...");
               };

               ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
               { 
                  var received_msg = evt.data;
                  alert("Message is received...");
               };

               ws.onclose = function()
               { 
                  alert("Connection is closed..."); 
               };

               window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
                  socket.close();
               };
            }

            else
            {
               alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
            }
         }
      </script>

   </head>
   <body>

      <div id="sse">
         <a href="javascript:WebSocketTest()">Run WebSocket</a>
      </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

Problem is, that with this I never see alert from 'onopen' function so it's not opened properly and readystatus is kept as 'connecting' instead of 'connected' all the time.

I've read a about response from server with some hash to acknowledge and finish handshake, but seen it in older examples of .NET and not with this TcpListener from Core 2... so I thought it's a part of BeginAcceptTcpClient function... and since it worked with .NET client I'm not really sure where is mistake.

Can anybody help me with this or hint how to implement handshake hash response, please?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found a problem. Client really did expected a hash in response to finish handshake... still don't undeastand why HTML did and .NET Client didn't want it.

I've created a new method for handshake to send required response:

```
private static void CompleteHandshake(IAsyncResult res)
{
    ClientPacket packet = (ClientPacket)res.AsyncState;
    Socket s = packet.client.Client;
    try
    {
        if (s.EndReceive(res) > 0)
        {
            var data = ByteArray.ReadString(packet.buffer);

            if (new Regex("^GET").IsMatch(data))
            {
                Byte[] response = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols" + Environment.NewLine
                    + "Connection: Upgrade" + Environment.NewLine
                    + "Upgrade: websocket" + Environment.NewLine
                    + "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: "
                    + Convert.ToBase64String(
                            SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(
                                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                                    new Regex("Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)").Match(data).Groups[1].Value.Trim() + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"
                                )
                            )
                    ) + Environment.NewLine
                    + Environment.NewLine);


                Console.WriteLine("Packet incoming");
                s.Send(response, 0, response.Length, SocketFlags.None);
            }
            s.BeginReceive(packet.buffer, 0, bufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveMessage), packet);
        }
        else
        {
            clients.Remove(packet);
            s.Close();
            packet = null;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        clients.Remove(packet);
        s.Close();
        packet = null;
    }
}
```

Then the only change in old code is in listener method AcceptClient where simple change method parameter of BeginReceive to redirect onto CompleteHandshake.

```
private static void AcceptClient(IAsyncResult res)
{
    TcpClient client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(res);
    client.NoDelay = true;

    ClientPacket packet = new ClientPacket(client);
    clients.Add(packet);

    client.Client.BeginReceive(packet.buffer, 0, bufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(CompleteHandshake), packet);
    StartListening();
}
```

That new method CompleteHandshake after sending hash response will redirect back to the old ReceiveMessage method where you can handle message however you need.

Comment: If you edited this to include how you had to modify the code in the question then you would have provided a useful answer. As it is, there is a chance that the link will change and the information won't be easily available to someone else in the future: [Wisdom of the Ancients](https://xkcd.com/979/).

Comment: Well, the browser connection is a WebSocket, and the .NET one is a pure TCP socket. They are not the same. WebSocket is a upgraded HTTP connection, made on a TCP socket.

Comment: Ye, it took me a while to catch it. :)